# Express GET Request Results in Error: "res.send is not a function"

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, postman

I am trying to get data from a SQL Server DB using node.  I can make a connection and get data by running functions, but I would like to turn the functions into API endpoints.

Based on the error it seems to me that the `res` variable isn't getting passed down into the last if statement, but I'm not seeing the issue.

I get a `res.send is not a function` error when using a `GET` method on this address from Postman.

```
let mssqlQuery = function(query, res) {
  sql.connect(dbConfig, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err)
      res.send(err)
    } else {
      let request = new sql.Request();
      request.query(query, function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err)
          res.send(err)
        } else {
          res.send(res) // res.send is not a function
        }
      })
    }
  })
}

// GET API
app.get("/api/address", function(req, res) {
  var query = "select * from address"
  mssqlQuery(query, res)
})
```

Is the `res` variable improperly scoped or might I have the wrong approach entirely?

Comment: The inner `res` of `request.query()` is shadowing the outer one of the function. change the name of one and you should be fine.

Comment: Can you send a code snippet?  I think I tried what you are stating, but still made an error.  are you referring to lines 8 and 13?  I edited the question to reflect my understanding of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sirko suggested, the res value was shadowed by an other variable. The corrected code:

```
let mssqlQuery = function(query, res) {
  sql.connect(dbConfig, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error while connecting database :- " + err)
      res.send(err)
    } else {
      let request = new sql.Request();
      request.query(query, function(err, resp) { // Changed res to resp
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err)
          res.send(err)
        } else {
          res.send(resp) // res.send is not a function
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```